# Replace javascript con metodo POST

Tags: javascript, post, str-replace

soy un poco nuevo en esto de Javascript y me confunde un poco las funciones, quisiera hacer un filtrado de palabras con replace.
Tengo lo siguiente

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
<textarea id="mensajeUsuario"></textarea>
<textarea hidden id="MensajeFinal"></textarea>
<button type="submit" >Enviar mensaje</button>
</form>
```

lo que busco hacer es que cuando  el usuario escriba en el textarea que es visible se pase al otro textarea con las palabras remplazadas al momento de dar al boton

```
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("mensajeUsuario");
text = text.replace('abc','xyz');
msn = document.getElementById("MensajeFinal").value = text;
</script>
```

desconzco si de esta manera esta se pueda pasar los datos, ya que el textarea que en este caso el segundo lo ocupo despues para poder visualizar el mensaje escrito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español!

En primer lugar, a la forma en la que estás obteniendo el texto del elemento `mensajeUsuario` le hace falta que especifiques la propiedad value:

```
var text = document.getElementById("mensajeUsuario").value;
```

Segundo, para reemplazar un solo caracter de la lista de caracteres `abc`, debes hacerlo usando una expresión regular, ya que con `replace('abc','xyz')` le estás diciendo `reemplazar el texto "abc" por el texto"xyz"`:

```
text = text.replace(/[abc]/g,'xyz');
```

Sin embargo, con esta instrucción estás reemplazando las letras `a`, `b` y `c` por la cadena `xyz`. Por este motivo, tendrás que crear un arreglo asociativo, a través del cual asignarás un nuevo valor a cada instancia del caracter encontrado:

```
var letras = {'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'};
```

Para poner todo esto en marcha, podés usar la función `match` para validar cuáles son las letras que se encuentran en la cadena, y posteriormente iterar el arreglo de respuesta y reemplazar individualmente cada resultado usando la función `reduce` en el arreglo generado por la función `match`:

```js
function reemplazarTexto(e) {
  // Prevenir evento submit
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var text = document.getElementById("mensajeUsuario").value;
  var letras = {'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'};
  document.getElementById("MensajeFinal").value = text.match(/[abc]/g).reduce((t,c) => t.replace(new RegExp(c,'g'),letras[c]),text);
  
  // Prevenir evento submit
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
<textarea id="mensajeUsuario"></textarea>
<button type="submit" onclick="reemplazarTexto(event); return false;">Enviar mensaje</button>
<textarea id="MensajeFinal"></textarea>
</form>
```